# Powershell: Trying to use get-wmiobject to return service status

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am receiving an access denied error when attempting to use the following to query a service on a Windows 2012 server:

```
 get-wmiobject -Class Win32_Service -comp 192.168.60.23 -cred lab\test -filter "name='tapisrv'"
```

If I use an account that is a domain admin for the -cred parameter, then of course everything works fine. However, using the test account I can't seem to make it work. Here are the things I have tried so far:

- Added test account to WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__ and Distributed COM users group
- Ensured Distributed COM group is added in dcomcnfg ->Component Services -> My Computer -> properties ->COM Security ->Launch and Activate Permissions
- Added test account to WMIMGMT.msc -> WMI Control -> Properties -> Security -> Root -> Security

Most of the troubleshooting steps have come from here:

- ["get-wmiobject win32_process -computername" gets error "Access denied , code 0x80070005"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952833/get-wmiobject-win32-process-computername-gets-error-access-denied-code-0x8)

Only way I can seem to get the test user to work is make him a local admin, which I do not want to do. Is there any configuration I am overlooking in order to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Since your issue is not PowerShell related but security related I think this might work better at SuperUser.

Comment: Is there a way to move it? I would be happy to put it (or ask that it be placed) in a more appropriate place.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it was obscure and I found it in the following post:

[Granting remote user (non admin) the ability to enumerate services in Win32_Service in namespace cimv2 using WMI & C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917477/granting-remote-user-non-admin-the-ability-to-enumerate-services-in-win32-serv)

sc sdset SCMANAGER D:(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCRPWPRC;;;SY)(A;;KA;;;BA)S:(AU;FA;KA;;;WD)(AU;OIIOFA;GA;;;WD)

I appreciate those trying to help!